# I get a "Undefined symbols" while using static inline member function, why?

Tags: c++

Here are my cpp files. cl.hpp/cl.cpp/main.cpp

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include "cl.hpp"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    cl::run1();
    cl::run();
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
//cl.hpp
#include <stdio.h>
class cl{
public:
    static inline void run();
    static void run1();
};
```

```cpp
//cl.cpp
#include "cl.hpp"
void cl::run(){
    printf("run run\n");
}

void cl::run1(){
    //cl::run();
    printf("run1 run1\n");
}
```

The Error Message is as follow:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "cl::run()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The compile command is "clang++ -std=c++17 cl.cpp main.cpp"
But When I change the code in cl.cpp into the following code , It works well.

```cpp
#include "cl.hpp"
void cl::run(){
    printf("run run\n");
}

void cl::run1(){
    cl::run();//the new line added
    printf("run1 run1\n");
}
```

Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: how do you compile and link the code?

Comment: `inline` function must be defined in every translation unit where it's used. If you don't want to have the definition in header, remove `inline`.

Comment: `//cl.cpp` is not including the header. I'd expect compiler errors for the posted code

Comment: Worth saying that `inline` functions are not necessarily inlined (in terms of code generation). If you want the definition in the header file make it `inline`, if you don't then don't. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: `<stdio.h>` -> `<cstdio>`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai
 clang++ -std=c++17 cl.cpp main.cpp

Comment: @Yksisarvinen But why the second version code wroks well

Comment: @john I know how to fix the compile error.I just want to know why it cannot compile, or why it works well in second version code.

Comment: @grayondream **Turn on all the warnings.** Even the second code snippet will give warning/error. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/8aO2d_7Nx)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9338189/12002570) where *"It's imperative that the function's definition (the part between the {...}) be placed in a header file, unless the function is used only in a single .cpp file.
In particular, **if you put the inline function's definition into a .cpp file and you call it from some other .cpp file, you'll get an "unresolved external" error from the linker.** "*

Comment: @grayondream You cannot declare a function inline unless you also make the definition of the function available in every place where the function is called. Of course that is most easily done by putting the definition in the header file.

Comment: @john sorry,it's just a typing mistake. it's hpp